# How can i remove instance of mysql from brew info mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I am trying to remove mysql from my macbook pro to start from fresh.

I have followed guides on how to remove all instances and files of mysql, however if i run

```
brew info mysql
```

I still get info pertaining to mysql 8.0 as follows:-

```
mysql: stable 8.0.12 (bottled)
Open source relational database management system
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/
Conflicts with:
mariadb (because mysql, mariadb, and percona install the same 
binaries.)
mariadb-connector-c (because both install plugins)
mysql-cluster (because mysql, mariadb, and percona install the same 
binaries.)
mysql-connector-c (because both install MySQL client libraries)
percona-server (because mysql, mariadb, and percona install the same 
binaries.)
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew- 
core/blob/master/Formula/mysql.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘
Required: openssl ✘
==> Requirements
Required: macOS >= 10.10 ✔
==> Options
--with-debug
Build with debug support
--with-embedded
Build the embedded server
--with-local-infile
Build with local infile loading support
--with-memcached
Build with InnoDB Memcached plugin
--with-test
Build with unit tests
==> Caveats
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure 
it run:
mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:
brew services start mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
mysql.server start
==> Analytics
install: 66,127 (30d), 215,889 (90d), 794,987 (365d)
install_on_request: 61,289 (30d), 185,026 (90d), 647,998 (365d)
build_error: 444 (30d)
```

How can i completely remove this? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql is already uninstalled. See these lines in the middle of your output:

```
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-
core/blob/master/Formula/mysql.rb
```

Homebrew is fetching this information on mysql's dependencies and usage remotely from GitHub. I do not have mysql installed either and get the same output when I run `brew info mysql`. If you try running `mysql` from the command line, you should get `-bash: mysql: command not found`.

Comment: Thankyou! I also realised this after posting, but thank you for confirming for me.